# How to get a specific pixel from multiple different raster to create a new raster

Tags: raster, r

I want to get a new climate data raster based on a series of climate data rasters.
The climate data raster is daily data.
I want to get different date raster to create a new raster.

[image]

This is the base date

[image]

This is the temperature at no.1 day of the year

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are looking for; let's say these are temperature layers, you want a mean of them all? or you want to re-scale?

Comment: I want to extract pixel value from multiple temperature raster layers to create a new raster, but every pixel might be from different layers of above temperature layers. maybe for a pixel is from no.1 temperature layer, but another pixel is from no.65 temperature layer.

Comment: how do you want to decide which layer do you take your pixel value from?

Comment: I have a base layer to choose that, this base layer include the date of every pixel

Comment: ok and the names of the temperature layers are the dates

Comment: yeah. but i have no idea of how to do this,

Comment: can you post a screenshot or copy paste the head of the date raster?

Comment: or just print the raster object, such as:` print(loss)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1558, 1610, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.00025, 0.00025  (x, y)
#extent      : -96.00825, -95.60575, 18.49275, 18.88225  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : memory 
#name        : Layer_1 
#min value   :       0 
#max value   :      19 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example should help you to follow it with your data; the principle is to filter values based on a condition, in this case where it matches the date, and take those temperature values and store them in a third raster, iterating on each value of your date raster.

```r
library(raster)

# create dummy raster stack
# you may use:
# t_files = list.files("C:/your_directory/")
# and rs = stack(t_files)
# and SKIP the for loop

rs = stack() 
for(i in 1:10) { 
  temp = raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
  values(temp) = (runif(100)*20)  %/% 1
  rs = stack(rs, temp)
}

#  set names of the "day of the year", we make them start with "t" in this case
names(rs) = paste0("t", 1:10)

# a raster with dates from 1 to 10
date_r = raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
values(date_r) = rep(1:10, each = 10)


# let's build the raster that will hold the data for each date 
final_r = raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
values(final_r) = 1


# sprintf() is to subset the stack to the desired layer from t1 to t10
# date_r[] == i subsets the pixels of date_r that are equal to the i date
for(i in 1:10) { 
  final_r[ date_r[] == i ] = rs[[sprintf("t%s", i)]][date_r[] == i]
}

par(mfrow = c(1,2) )
plot(final_r)
text(final_r)
plot(rs$t1)
text(rs$t1)

# as you may see, values from final correspond to those in t1 at those pixels at date == 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !  Especially for the principle!

Comment: If the answer helps you solve your problem you may upvote or mark as accepted answer accordingly